# How can I change a jQuery UI widget's options after it has been created?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

It seems that the usual method of making jQuery widgets is to call a function on an element, passing the options as a parameter, and then not touching the widget directly again.  Is there a way to change a widget's options after it has been created?

I want to create a draggable box that is aligned to a grid, but if the user resizes the page, I want to scale the grid.  In the window resize event, how can I access the `grid` property of the draggable element?

```
$('.box').draggable({grid: [40,40]});
...
$(window).resize(function(){ ??? });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the Jquery ui documentation:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "grid", [50, 20] );
```

So you can do

```
$( ".box" ).draggable( "option", "grid", [width, height] );
```

Comment: I am doing exactly this, http://jsfiddle.net/bz2aeLrg/1/

But it seems I need to refresh/update the widget after that. In the sample after you click the `Change Mode` button, the property is updated but the UI is updated only if I resize the browser window.

Comment: got it. `$(window).resize();});`