# which is the default dialog jquery show

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to return the default value of a Jquery dialog after having been changed to show: "slow".

I have a normal dialog:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog();
```

that change after a dialog with effect:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: "slow" });
```

and I need put its default value. What is the Effect "none"?

i try this but it not work for me:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: "" });
```

Comment: Default duration is `400`. [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Dialog's API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-show):

> **`show`**
>
> **Type**: Number or String or Object
>
> **Default**: `null`

For example,

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: null });
```

You may want to check [How can I change a jQuery UI widget's options after it has been created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7997561/417685) to avoid reinitializing it everytime.

Comment: What you are doing `$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: null });` is initializing the dialog with the same default value.. which happens already. but OP wants to set it to `slow` during init and change it to default later.

Comment: "*What is the Effect "none"?*," I'm aware OP already knows how to change the property. The example is conforming what it is intended in the answer - show that `null` can be used in `show` :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like below,

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "show", null );
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pWbbh/ (Dialog `autoOpen` with `slow`.. close the dialog and hit Open button to see it opening instantly.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ show: false });
```

use false instead leaving it blank. try out the bin: http://jsbin.com/awozor/1/edit